# How can I represent an int value as a char/string (C#)?

Tags: c#, string, char, int

How can I represent an int value as a char/string (c#)? 
For example, if int = 3 and char = 'C', it should show me as a result CCC.

(I am a beginner, please keep it simple D; and thx )

Comment: See here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.-ctor?view=netframework-4.8#System_String__ctor_System_Char_System_Int32_

Answer (score 2):

Not very clear title question but is that you want?

```
string str = new string('C', 3);
```

This string constructor creates a new string instance from a char repeated n times.

You can write that too:

```
char letter = 'C';
int count = 3;

string result = new string(letter, count);
```